# Background image not working after deployment

Tags: css, reactjs

i have the following issue : background image was perfectly working, then after deployment it's not, the image is in a folder in the public folder here is my code :
react component :

```
function Header() {
return (
    <div className="bannerContainer">
        <div className="banner">
            <h1>news reader</h1>
            
        </div>
        <h3>USER GUID</h3>
    </div>
    )
}
```

css styling :

```
.banner {
height: 20vh;
width: 100%;
background-image: url('/images/banner1.png');  
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat; 
}
```

Comment: Needs details or clarity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'/images/banner1.png'` is an **absolute path**. It will start at whatever is considered to be the *root*. This can be different for your local environment and deployed environment.

It's best practice to use **relative paths**, so that it is not dependent on where the root starts:

```css
background-image: url('../relative/path/to/banner1.png');       /* example 1 */
background-image: url('./also/relative/path/to/banner1.png');   /* example 2 */
```

**EDIT:** To test whether the problem is with your url, replace your path with a regular image link we *know* works. Something like:

```
background-image: url("https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png");
```

If the image **does** appear in the background, then the problem is definitely with your image path.

In that case I'd recommend playing around with it. Place the image in the *same folder* as the CSS file trying to access it, and see if you can get any success there before moving the image further away.

Comment: i'm trying and it's not working

Comment: I've edited my answer with some ideas on debugging it further :)

Comment: i did what you exactly said, it works with regular image url, so the problem is in the image path, thank you for making it easier

Comment: No problem! You could try something like this [relative path calculator](https://www.stevebreese.com/Relative-Path-Calculator) to double check your path if you're still having trouble.

Comment: it's solved , i use {background-image: url('./banner1.png');} after changing the image location to the components file, thank you so much for help

Comment: Glad to hear it! You can mark the answer as accepted if it helped you :)

Comment: i'm new here i can't push your answer up :v sorry :D i'll do it when a get more than 15 reputation thanks again